# How would I create a Custom TFS Checkin Policy to check code for coding standards?

Tags: vb.net, tfs

I am working with a tremendous amount of legacy code written to various code standards over the last 15+ years. Currently, we use TFS for our version control, changing is not an option. Rewriting all the legacy code to current standards at one time is also not an option. The code base, needs to improve in order for us to decouple our various layers and move to a model more like MVC.

What I am looking for is a way to run some form of custom code analysis on just the files being committed at the time. Something along the lines of a regex check for certain strings in files where they shouldn't exist (e.g. ExecuteScalar() in an aspx.vb file) Essentially, I want to know if developers are writting code that doesn't match our standards, or if the files they are committing contain code that doesn't match our standard. The idea being, that we will immediately force developers to write code to standards, and incrementally update the files they are working with to current standards. Over time this should result in a cleaner code base.

I have been working my way through the MSDN Documentation for TFS Checkin policies but I'm not really finding what I'm looking for. Most of the documentation seems to refer to running Code Analysis on the entire project and creating work tickets for cleanup. A possible solution, but less than ideal.

Are there any prewritten custom TFS Checkin Policies that do this? If not, how would one go about writing something like this?

Answer (score 3):

I think running static code analysis only on the code that has changed would be pretty difficult.  We wanted to track unit test coverage in a similar way and ended up looking at the total coverage numbers and added a PowerShell script to our build which fails the build when total coverage drops which implies that someone added code without unit tests.

You could do something similar where you look at the total number of code standard issues and use a custom PowerShell script to fail the build when the number increases.  This should help your team foster continuous improvement of of their coding standards.

There is default Code Analysis check-in policy in the box with TFS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So this is a bit outdated for TFS2008 but you can use it as a guideline for creating a custom code analysis policy. [TFS 2008 Code Analysis check-in policy](http://weblogs.asp.net/uruit/writing-custom-rules-for-tfs-2008-code-analysis-check-in-policy) 
Having the code analysis throw build errors for any rules that fail should help with enforcing your legacy code standards.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, you want to stop any new Code Analysis violations from being committed into TFS (and reduce the existing debt). The first part you can do easily if you're running VS2015 Update 1. You will need to define a custom CA policy where violations are marked as errors and not warnings. Then in VS, you can right-click the project and choose **Analyze/Run Code Analysis and Suppress Active Issues**. This will create a **GlobalSupressions** file in the same location as the .vbproj.

This creates a baseline of CA errors which essentially you are sweeping under the rug for now but importantly you will stop any new errors.

Next you need to add Code Analysis to the check in policy as @chief7 suggests. This will ensure that Code Analysis has been run on the code to be committed to source. (You can actually configure the .vbproj to run Code Analysis on build).

So now that you have fixed the leak, you need to repay the debt, reduce the existing CA errors. In VS 2015 Update 1, you can show errors only from **Changed Documents**, unfilter the supressed issues and you can fix away. This would be a manual step that you can ask developers to get into the habit of doing.

Whilst I am certain that this all works for C#, I am assuming that it will for VB but I don't know for sure.